# Getting x number of files after a certain file

Tags: c#, linq, file, fileinfo

I have a folder with Jpeg-files which i want too pull 3-4 at a time after sorting them for when they were lastly written. The thing is that i want to specify a start location (by file name) and only pull from there.

Example of a directory with pictures,

- a.jpg
- b.jpg
- c.jpg
- d.jpg
- e.jpg
- f.jpg
- etc until j.jpg

Now i want to get 3 files starting from b.jpg, meaning that i want to order the files, search for a specific file (in this case b.jpg) and then take the following 3 files that comes after b.jpg (c.jpg, d.jpg and e.jpg in the example above).

How can i find the index of b.jpg using LINQ or better yet, get the 3 files in the same query?

```
index of file/the files directly = Directory.GetFiles(pathToFiles, "*.jpg").Select(x => new FileInfo(x)).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime)... ?
```

Comment: Since `Directory.GetFiles` returns `string[]`, you can use the `string[].IndexOf` method to find the index.  Sounds like you can take it from there.  Honestly I don't know how people learn LINQ before they learn the basics like arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look into the [`SkipWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549288(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method, the [`Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method, and then the [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method.

Additionally, utilize the [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

---

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathToFiles, "*.jpg")
                     .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime)
                     .SkipWhile(x => !String.Equals(x.Name, "b.jpg")
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Take(3);
```

Basically, once you have your ordered sequence, skip everything until you reach the "b.jpg" file, then skip that one file, then take the next three.

---

Update: Now that I think about it, the `EnumerateFiles` will help a bit, but not entirely since you negate deferred execution with ordering. But, it'll still be a slight advantage (I think).

Comment: the second closing parenthesis is missed on line `SkipWhile(`

Comment: also instead of `Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathToFiles, "*.jpg").Select(x => new FileInfo(x))` we can directly use: `new DirectoryInfo(pathToFiles).EnumerateFiles("*.jpg")` such that we don't need to create `new FileInfo` on each item